# How can I disable the button in design as well?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

What I'm trying to do is to disable a button in style after the user has added 2 input boxes for a client. I'm using Tailwind CSS
Currently, the button is disabled after 2 boxes are added,  but I want to disable it in a style as well, to make it gray for example.

```
<button className="btn-main" 
        disabled={this.state.items.length >= 2} 
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
            <PlusSmIcon className="h-5 w-5 mr-2" />
            Add Clinet(s)
</button>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

[you can prefix tailwind classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#disabled) with `disabled:` (eg. `disabled:border-red-500`) for styles you want to apply when a button/input/etc is disabled.

you *might* need to enable this in your `tailwind.config.js` file like so:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    extend: {
      opacity: ['disabled'],
      border: ['disabled'],
      // add any tailwind classes you wish to enable disabled: on here  
    }
  },
}
```

Otherwise, you can target a disabled button with regular CSS:

```
.btn-main {
  // regular button styles
}

.btn-main:disabled {
  // these styles will be applied to any disabled buttons with the .btn-main class
}
```

Comment: for me disabled: prefix worked without any additional configuration on tailwind.config.js as the answerer had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a class or styles on disabled condition:

Approach # 1

```
<button className={`btn-main ${this.state.items.length >= 2 && 'disabled'}`} 
        disabled={this.state.items.length >= 2} 
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
            <PlusSmIcon className="h-5 w-5 mr-2" />
            Add Clinet(s)
</button>
```

Approach # 2 by adding conditional styles in style props but still I will recommend you approach 1

```
  <button className="btn-main"
        style={{color:this.state.items.length >= 2?"red":"white"}}
        disabled={this.state.items.length >= 2} 
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
            <PlusSmIcon className="h-5 w-5 mr-2" />
            Add Clinet(s)
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well using css you can add bellow style for the element that will avoid all kinds of click events

```
pointer-events: none
```

You can also make it generic by adding a disabled attribute to the button and then add bellow styles to your css file.

```
button[disabled='true']{
 pointer-events: none
}
```